Not sure what to do about condensation in crawlspace
New build home on flat land in Utah. Summer temps have peaked in the 100s. We have condensation on the inside of the vapor barrier on 2 of the exterior walls in the crawlspace. Inspector told us it’s fairly normal but not acceptable. Recommended to remove the plastic, see if it helps and maybe install a dehumidifier. Do we need this plastic? Do we need to replace with a different style vapor barrier? Is there something else we need to check/be concerned about (mold)?
https://imgur.com/a/B5w5EBc

Usually plastic under the floor is the wrong spot to put it in a crawl space. Is the rest of your crawl space encapsulated? If it is, is the encapsulation in good condition? Is your crawlspace vented? You shouldn't need to end up with a dehumidifier in your crawl space when all is said and done.
